# Loading Google Maps Asynchronously for Specific Address

Tags: javascript, google-maps, asynchronous

Apologies in advance if this has already been answered. But I have spent several hours reading through all the suggestions at stackoverflow and couldn't figure out how to make them work for me, so I finally decided to ask. I am a javascript dummy :(

I like the following because I don't need to find the LatLng. As long as I have an address I can get the map. Plus as a bonus I can also have my own pointer. Works perfectly! But it sometimes slows down loading the page becaue the map has to load first before the rest of the page loads. I was wondering if somecan can be good enough to show me how to load the following asynchronously?

Thank you in advance and regards,

Mike

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Google Map</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style>
 body, html {width:100%;height:100%}
 #map {margin:25px;width:50%;height:50%}
</style>

<body>

<!-- Google Maps Start -->
<div id="map">
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var address = '6925 Hollywood Blvd., CA 90028';
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { 
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      zoom: 12
  });
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({
     'address': address
  }, 

  function(results, status) {
     if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        new google.maps.Marker({
           position: results[0].geometry.location,
           map: map,
           icon: 'img/maps_marker.png'
        });
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
     }
  });
</script> 
</div>
<!-- Google Maps End --> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the code**

```
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
}

function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&' +
      'callback=initialize';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;
```

For more information visit

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async

Comment: Thanks Manish Mudgal. Actually I saw that but I just couldn't figure out how to make that work for what I am trying to do. I have a database with 100's of addresses and I don't have LatLng and that is my first problem.I also like to use my own custom marker. Is it possible to make my code to work? I think the problem is with how "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" loads

Comment: Fire your custom code after map loads. It has load events which you can use to make sure that your code gets fired after map is loaded. If this answer is useful then please accept this as answer.

Comment: Sorry I am an accountant trying to figure this out. I don't know how to make the custom code fire after the map loads. Any chance you can show me an example please?

Comment: Hello All, I am still struggling with this. If there's a programmer who is willing to help make this work exactly the way I want, I will be happy to pay you. I can only pay through pay pal though. Please contact me at mike.osman@mail.com